# AWS amplify and graphql - External Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have a full stack amplify app using reactJS, Graphql and aws DynamoDB.
For customer purpose, i need to have the database host in my country (France). For now i have 30 tables store in aws dynamoDB, and i use GraphQL API in my front to query my data.

Is it possible to migrate all the tables and data to a server in france and link it to my aws amplify app and still using graphql API and graphQL Schema to query my new database ?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  An AppSync [lambda resolver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html) is commonly used to "proxy" GraphQL calls to a database, which can be AWS or external.  This means writing lambda code to make client calls on the database and returning the result to AppSync.  Similarly, A [http resolver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-http-resolvers.html) can return data to AppSync from any arbitrary HTTP endpoint like an external REST API.

In your case, though, wouldn't it be easier to migrate your DynamoDB tables or your all your app's AWS resources to [AWS's eu-west-3 Paris Region](https://aws.amazon.com/local/france/paris/)?